# LED strips on separate shelves

Tags: led, shelving, shelf

I just bought LED strips that works with Alexa, so if i want it to work must be connected to that exactly power source, i want to install it in 3 different shelves that are going to be separate but i need them to be connected somehow but i don't want the strip to be hanging on the air between shelves, any idea of how can i do that if it’s possible? I cannot come up with a clear smart idea yet

Comment: Cut the strip as needed. Solder wires from the end of one piece to the start of another. If you don't want to cut, you could put blobs of poster putty over LEDs you want to hide on the outside.

Comment: What is exactly that power source, are there multiple strips ? What kinds of connections are there now?  if you take the tour it will give you tips on how the site works And may help get better answers but I thought siding unwanted LED’s with poster putty was a good idea if 1 long strip.

Comment: Is the LED light strips LV 24 volts, or 120?  The power in the individual wires to the LED, not the power source.  Can you  provide the exact brand and model.

Answer (score 0):

If the power is through a power wart, and you are using Alexa, I am assuming it those multi-color 4 wire strips which are 24 volts.  Also the strips will have cut marks every 4 inches.  There are solderless LED Tee clips that would allow you to do what your want.

1. Cut the strips on the cut mark for each of the shelves
2. Put an L or Tee connect on the end of the shelves
3. In between the shelves, you would use connector with wires to go down the vertical edge

I would not solder, unless you know how to solder tiny connection points and you have the appropriate solder tool.  These are very thin printed circuit board.

If 120 power, the strips will NOT have cut marks.  and it would be difficult to add wire splices without using junction boxes.